# Access Error: Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I Know similar questions have been asked, but I still can't figure out this error.

I am working in Access, exporting to excel and used some excel macros to format the data and create charts. I am now trying to put those charts into a Powerpoint, and I am having trouble pasting only one of the four charts I am trying to copy over.

My code to export the third and fourth charts is as follows:

```
          xl.Sheets("Sheet with chart 3").Select
          Set rng = xl.ActiveChart
          rng.CopyPicture
          mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
          Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            myShapeRange.Left = 365
            myShapeRange.Top = 200
            myShapeRange.Width = 345

          xl.Sheets("Sheet with chart 4").Select
          Set rng = xl.ActiveChart
          rng.CopyPicture
          mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
          Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            myShapeRange.Left = 365
            myShapeRange.Top = 200
            myShapeRange.Width = 345
```

I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)" on the second occurrence of the line

```
rng.CopyPicture
```

So why would this code fail after running three times prior? I believe I qualified everything correctly, and this code isn't running inside a with block either. Also, The excel sheet it is pulling from is practically identical to the others.

Comment: You have an extra `"` after `"Sheet with Chart 4""`.

Comment: Oops, good find, but that's not how it's typed in the actual program, just a typo when I changed the names of the excel sheets.

Comment: Is this sheet (with Chart 4) the last one by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it is. I experimented with adding an extra blank sheet at the end of the excel book and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you taken into account the possibility that the sheet numbering starts at 0? I'm wondering if all of your functions are actually pulling data from the next sheet along; and then when we reach the last one, there is nothing there? EDIT: maybe not then, I'll have another think

Comment: The indexing starts at 1. 'Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(0)' gives an index out of bounds error, and' Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(8)' does not in a book with eight sheets

Comment: Honestly I don't even think Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(8) is necessary for this chunk of code, as xlSheet is never referenced, only the variable xl. My bad.

Comment: You're right about that actually. In that case there is no discernible difference between the two procedures so it's hard to suggest anything unless you can provide the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been stuck on this for awhile, the problem was caused by this line:

```
xlSheet.Range("G7").Select
```

which was the last line during the formatting on the excel book. I had recorded macros in excel to make the charts and pasted the resulting code in Access. I guess having this cell selected was preventing the chart from being set to active, so I couldn't copy it. Hopefully this helps someone having the same silly problem I was!